# JSP file upload with modified filename

Tags: file, upload

I am developing a Job Portal website using JSP and Oracle XE.Now,a Job Seeker is supposed to upload his Resume/CV.Say,this filename is Resume.pdf.Next, another job seeker uploads his Resume.pdf(same name).I want to avoid saving files with same name.One adviced me to concatinate the date with the filename when storing in database.But I want to concatenate the Jobseeker ID (created by Sequence in oracle) with this filename.
The issue is:When file is uploaded, I don't need the Connection string.I need it only during writing the filename to the database.Without this condition, I have successfully uploaded files.
I am giving the codes for the sequence and insert-procedure.

```
create sequence js_id_seq
increment by 1 
start with 100
nocache
nocycle;
/

create or replace procedure js_file_prefx(prefx out varchar2)
is
begin
select 'JS'||js_id_seq.**nextval** into prefx from dual;
end;
/
create or replace procedure ins_job_seekr (
name varchar2,
paswd varchar2,
profile varchar2,
email varchar2,
address varchar2,
phone number,
resume varchar2
)
is
begin
insert into employer values(
'JS'||js_id_seq.**currval**,
name,
paswd,
profile,
email,
address,
phone,
resume
 );
end;
/
```

---

JSP code part:

```
 String emp_file="";

boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
String  Filename1 ="";
File file;
String filePath="";

if (!isMultipart) 
{

} 
else {


DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

------  //not giving code this part as this was working fine
 else {

        try {   //if i put connection string here, it says that its a different    
              //instance of hr

             CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall("{call emp_file_prefx(?)}");

       cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.VARCHAR);
       cs.execute();
       emp_file= cs.getString(1); 

            Filename1 = item.getName();
            filePath=config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"upload_data\\";

            Filename=Filename1.substring( Filename1.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

           Filename=Filename + emp_file;

            if(Filename!="")
                {  file = new File( filePath +Filename) ;
                   item.write(file);
                }

              }
        catch(Exception err)
            {
                out.println(err.getMessage());
            }

        }
   }

  try
    {
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","hr","hr");
    CallableStatement cs1=con.prepareCall("{call ins_job_seekr(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

    cs1.setString(1,c_name);
cs1.setString(2,paswrd);
cs1.setString(3,c_prof);
cs1.setString(4,mail);
cs1.setString(7,addres);
    cs1.setInt(8,Integer.parseInt(phone_no));
cs1.setString(9,Filename);


cs1.execute();
    out.println("Insert successful");



    //con.close();
   }
  catch(Exception err)
  {
   out.println(err.getMessage());
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the job seeker has to log in to your site. You most likely may have a session object around which will help you to identify your user. You could store the Jobseeker ID in the session when she log in and read it from there when you create the filename on upload.

When the file was successfully written to the server you just have to put the filename in the database.

Comment: thanx for the reply.But i actually wanted to upload the file during registration.I found out a solution myself though by passing the emp_file content to the callable statement to insert into Job seeker's database.of course, i had to modify the procedure to insert.